# set a ul size according to the div that containes it

Tags: html, css

I need to have some elements to fill only the space of the element that contains it, for exemple, this is the code:

```
<header class="w_head">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <ul class="w_social text-right">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/Twitter_logo_blue.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/g+images-2013-01-15/g+ icon/Desktop/44dp/2x/btn_white.png"/></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </header>
```

and the styling:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container-fluid{
    position:relative;
}

.w_head{
    background-color: #66757f;
    height: 2.6em;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I need the ul to automatically be placed only inside and according to the header size and not the whole document.

Comment: You need to try what you say.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: the ul element there don't care about the header size but the size of the image inside it, i want the opposite.

Comment: i'm also not sure what you want. I wrote an answer of what i think you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an outer container and make it have an overflow...

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
       <li>whatever</li>
   </ul>
</div>

#container{
height:100px;
width:300px;
overflow-y:auto; 
overflow-x:none; 
border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Le454nd/ <--working demo

Comment: but i was thinking since there are images inside, how to compress the images size ?

Comment: you can compress images by having an thumbnail image. Or by setting the height and width tags on the img 
`<img src="whatever" width="40" height="40" alt="this is a 40x40 picture" />`

Answer (score 0):

Right from what you have wrote and I could be wrong, please let me know.
You want the `UL` to be `100%` of what the `w_head` is as it stands you already have this.

If `w_head` is `600px` wide so will the `UL`, just be aware that if body is `800px` and `w_head` is set to `100%` as it currently is this mean really `w_head` is `800px` and so will the `UL`.

Comment: yes, and so the height. then ul would consider the w_head's height and width, and resize according.
i'm sorry if i'm being incomprehensible !!

Comment: yes for the width height is a different story, but if it is dynamically changing content so it could be 3 li or 10 then change the height of the w_head to auto rather than 2.6em

Comment: no problem height is always a funny one when you do not want to fix it to a set height, have a good one..